# Unable to share url on whatsapp for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, whatsapp

I have the code below which i am using to share the url on whatsapp using whatsapp url scheme, but when i do this i see empty message on the whatsapp message screen.

```
let itunesLink = "http://google.com";
let text = itunesLink.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet());
let url  = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(text!)")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!);
```

When this code runs, i see the contacts and after i select the whatsapp account option i dont see the url and see the empty screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am always confused why there are so many allowed characters in these sets. I suspect you may need to add more percent-encoding. This is what I use to encode URLs embedded in URLs:

```
let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ".-0123456789@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz~")
let text = itunesLink.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(set)
```

Because "/" is an allowed character in a URL Path, `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet` includes "/", and the "/" in `itunesLink` will not be percent-encoded, using the original program. That might be confusing Whatsapp. It certainly confuses me.